# How do I remove a dishwasher that is screwed to a granite countertop?

Tags: screws, removal, granite

The company that installed the granite countertops attached the dishwasher to the granite. I need to know how to remove the screws, without damaging the granite, in order to replace the dishwasher.

Comment: Be aware that dishwasher width may vary. When I replaced mine, the new one required that I widen the opening about an inch. The cabinets _did_ have scribe fitting overhangs that I could trim back to achieve this, but it could have been ugly if they didn't. If at all possible I suggest getting the old one out, checking the opening size and how much room there is for adaptation, and getting the actual (rather than nominal) dimensions of the proposed replacement before paying for it -- or buy it with installation service included so this is Someone Else's Problem.

Answer (score 8):

Unscrew the screws, using a screwdriver. There's no reason to think doing that will damage the granite. Almost certainly, the screws have been driven into plastic or lead inserts that are placed into holes drilled in the granite. Your new dishwasher may not have the mounting holes in exactly the same position, and will require similar inserts installed accordingly.

Comment: Also, there is sometimes simply a stamped metal bar that is placed across the adjoining cabinets, with many little holes to accommodate various models of dishwasher.